# How to get each array of String with the largest number and with an unique key?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList<String[]>` which contains the following data:

```
[Branford, Paddock Lane, 136, 1]
[Branford, Paddock Lane, 42, 3]
[Branford, Hartford Road, 117, 0]
[Branford, Hartford Road, 45, 3]
[McAlister, Sigourney Street, 103, 3]
[McAlister, Sigourney Street, 61, 1]
[McAlister, Stanford Street, 1, 3]
[McAlister, Stanford Street, 34, 4]
[Cypress Gardens, Route 115, 112, 12]
[Cypress Gardens, Park Road, 10, 4]
[Cypress Gardens, Park Road, 49, 4]
[Cypress Gardens, Old Farm Road, 28, 5]
[Cypress Gardens, Old Farm Road, 79, 3]
[Germfask, Exeter Court, 28, 7]
[Germfask, South Boulevard, 119, 6]
[Germfask, South Boulevard, 135, 3]
[Minford, Liberty Lane, 41, 3]
[Minford, Liberty Lane, 52, 4]
[Minford, State Street West, 103, 0]
```

The first element from each array of strings is a city's name and the last element is a counter. I need to extract data which will contain also array of strings but only with one city name and the largest counter. For example, for `Branford` the result will be `[Branford, Paddock Lane, 42, 3]`. How can I extract this data only with `forEach` loops?
Thank you.

I have tried by using a `forEach` through the `ArrayList` and comparing each counter from current element with the next one where the city name is the same.

The output is not as expected, as it contains no data.

```
final int[] max = {Integer.parseInt(arrayListSrc.get(0)[3])};
ArrayList<String[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(1);
final int[] index = {0};
arrayListSrc.forEach(strings -> {
  if (strings[0].equals(arrayListSrc.get(index[0])[0])) {
    if (Integer.parseInt(strings[3]) < Integer.parseInt(arrayListSrc.get(index[0])[3])) {
      if (Integer.parseInt(arrayListSrc.get(index[0])[3]) > max[0]) {
        max[0] = Integer.parseInt(arrayListSrc.get(index[0])[3]);
        arrayList.add(strings);
      }
    }
  }
  index[0]++;
});
```

Comment: Why not `Branford, Paddock Lane, 42, 3`?

Comment: Please edit into the question the minimal code that demonstrates what you have attempted so far.

Comment: @forpas oops, my bad.

Comment: @KevinO i have added the code

Comment: Your code is extremely hard to read, probably also for you, for several reasons. You're using meaningless names (arrayListSrc strings). You're using magic numbers everywhere. You're using strings to represent integers. You shouldn't be dealing with a List<String[]>. You should be dealing with a List<Address>, where Address is a class with a city, a street, a number and a counter. Naming things and using the right types makes things much much easier.

Comment: What represent last two numbers in your arraylist? @VitaliyKalmyk

Comment: @MS90 the first number is the street number and the second is a count

Comment: I don't think you understood the reason behind @forpas' remark. Branford is listed twice with a count of 3. How to handle entries with the same count for the same city?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had something like this:

```
Map<String, String[]> result = new TreeMap<>();


for(String[] s : source) {
    if(!result.containsKey(s[0])){
        result.put(s[0], s);
    } else if (Integer.valueOf(result.get(s[0])[3]) < Integer.valueOf(s[3])) {
        result.put(s[0], s);
    }
}

for(String k : result.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(k + ": " + Arrays.toString(result.get(k)));
}
```

This should print:

```
Branford: [Branford, Paddock Lane, 42, 3]
Cypress Gardens: [Cypress Gardens, Route 115, 112, 12]
Germfask: [Germfask, Exeter Court, 28, 7]
McAlister: [McAlister, Stanford Street, 34, 4]
Minford: [Minford, Liberty Lane, 52, 4]
```

Is that the result you are after? You do have the challenge that you have entries with the same number of hits.

Comment: Yes, that is the result I was after. Thank a lot for your explanation

Comment: @VitaliyKalmyk Please use the accept answer and upvote buttons to convey this.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, try to map your `String[]` to a suitable data structure next time, since it will be a lot easier to handle. Just create a suitable class, thats what object oriented programming is for.

But, to answer the question, you can map the plain `List<String[]>` in the following way:

```
Map<String, String[]> results = source.stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], Function.identity(),
                BinaryOperator.maxBy(
                        Comparator.comparing(s -> Integer.valueOf(s[3])))));
```

The result is a Map where the key represents the city name and the value is the original `String[]` maxed by the counter. This solution does not require the use of `forEach()`, but rather stream operations to achieve the expected result.

You can, however, use `forEach()` to print or further operate on the results:

```
results.forEach((s, strings) -> {
    System.out.println(s + " " + Arrays.toString(strings));
});
```

Comment: Well, you have right approach, but why not putting it to a List? @Glains